# How does the "if" shell command work?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, background, terminal

I know how the `if` shell command is used. But how does it actually work? Everything I found about it online only explains how it is used.

Is it a built in feature of the shell or is it just a regular command that I could write myself too?

```
if echo "test"; then mkdir one; else mkdir two; fi
```

Does this call an `if` command with `echo "test"` as its arguments? Does it "remember" the result, so that the next time a `then` or `else` command is executed, they can decide whether to actually run or not?

Or does the shell parse something like this and directly executes `echo "test"`? If so, why do we need a terminating `;` or `\n`? Couldn't it just scan to the `then` keyword?

Comment: `which if` and `man if` would tell you if it's a built-in or full-blown executable. `if` is also usually used with `[`, which (oddly enough) **IS** a full-blown exectuable...

Comment: `if` is not a command. It's a keyword to indicate a conditional branch in the shell's grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this call an `if` command with `echo "test"` as its arguments? Does it "remember" the result, so that the next time a `then` or `else` command is executed, they can decide whether to actually run or not?

`if`, `then`, and `else` are shell keywords, and are special-cased.

> Or does the shell parse something like this and directly executes echo "test"? If so, why do we need a terminating ; or \n? Couldn't it just scan to the then keyword?

It needs the command terminator so that it knows that the arguments to the command have terminated. Otherwise, `then` will be passed as an argument to the command.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it only uses the result of the last expression before the `then` part:

```
if true;        then echo y; else echo n; fi    # y
if false;       then echo y; else echo n; fi    # n
if true; false; then echo y; else echo n; fi    # n
if false; true; then echo y; else echo n; fi    # y
```

If the result (i.e. `$?`) is zero, the `then` part executes, otherwise the `else` part. Constructs such as `test ...`, `[ ... ]`, `[[ ... ]]`, `(( ... ))` etc. evaluate an expression and returns either true or false which is why they can be used in the `if` statement.

Bash's `man` page says the syntax of an if statement is `if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi` and that "A  list  is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators `;`, `&`, `&&`, or `||`, and optionally terminated by one of `;`, `&`, or `<newline>`."

Since it's a shell builtin, it probably doesn't have to "remember" anything; you could in principle write your own conditional construct by having `my_if` save the result of executing its argument(s), `my_then` only execute its argument(s) if it's `true`, and `my_else` only if it's `false`. However this could be easily abused or used incorrectly, while bash's `if` statement requires a very specific syntax.

But even then you couldn't make it work exactly like `if`. The above example would become:

```
#my_if true; false; ...  # this wouldn't work since my_if ends at the first ;

my_if 'true; false;'; my_then echo y; my_else echo n; # and perhaps my_fi
```

Finally you wouldn't (easily) be able to nest your `my_if`s unless you use some complex array of stored states or something.

In conclusion, you may be able to replicate some of the `if` yourself but probably not all of it, at least not in a way that is more meaningful to use than regular `if`.